# digits to words from sys.stdin

Tags: python, words, digits

I'm trying to convert digits to words from std input (txt file).
If the input is for example : 1234, i want the output to be one two three four, for the next line in the text file i want the output to be on a new line in the shell/terminal:
1234 one two three four
56 five six
The problem is that i can't get it to output on the same line.
Code so far :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import math

def main():
    number_list = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
    for line in sys.stdin:
        number = line.split()

        for i in number:
            number_string = "".join(i)
            number2 = int(number_string)
            print(number_list[number2])
main()
```

Comment: I don't want to print all output on the same line, but for every line of input, i want a line of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the words in a list, join them, and print the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import math

def main():
        number_list = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
        for line in sys.stdin:
                digits = list(line.strip())
                words =  [number_list[int(digit)] for digit in digits]
                words_line = ' '.join(words)
                print(words_line)
main()
```

Comment: Happy to help. If an answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.